# Fast vector math in Clojure / Incanter

Tags: r, vector, clojure, incanter

I'm currently looking into Clojure and Incanter as an alternative to R. (Not that I dislike R, but it just interesting to try out new languages.) I like Incanter and find the syntax appealing, but vectorized operations are quite slow as compared e.g. to R or Python.

As an example I wanted to get the first order difference of a vector 
using Incanter vector operations, Clojure map and R . Below is the code and timing for all 
versions. As you can see R is clearly faster.

Incanter and Clojure:

```
(use '(incanter core stats)) 
(def x (doall (sample-normal 1e7))) 
(time (def y (doall (minus (rest x) (butlast x))))) 
"Elapsed time: 16481.337 msecs" 
(time (def y (doall (map - (rest x) (butlast x))))) 
"Elapsed time: 16457.850 msecs"
```

R:

```
rdiff <- function(x){ 
   n = length(x) 
   x[2:n] - x[1:(n-1)]} 
x = rnorm(1e7) 
system.time(rdiff(x)) 
   user  system elapsed 
  1.504   0.900   2.561
```

So I was wondering is there a way to speed up the vector operations in Incanter/Clojure? Also solutions involving the use of loops, Java arrays and/or libraries from Clojure are welcome.

I have also posted this question to Incanter Google group with no responses so far.

**UPDATE:** I have marked Jouni's answer as accepted, see below for my own answer where I have cleaned up his code a bit and added some benchmarks.

Comment: That's going to be difficult, as the intrinsic looping of R is programmed in C or Fortran. Getting faster than that will take quite some effort...

Comment: I don't necessarily wan't to get faster than R, but I'd like to know if there is way to speed up the Clojure operation to at least get closer.

Comment: This is in line with the experience I had previously; Clojure is slower on basic operations almost by a factor of 10.  My advice: don't use Clojure if you're looking for performance; use it if you want to have seamless integration on the JVM, etc.  You may also find this question relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186709/are-there-any-good-clojure-benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks Shane, I'll have a look at that. Clojure loops are faster than R which triggered my interest in the first place, but most of my analysis is based on vectorized operations so thats much more significant for me.

Comment: rdiff could be better written as `x[-1] - x[-n]`.

Comment: Or as `diff` (already exists).  As, for example, `{ tmp <- rnorm(1e7); all(diff(tmp) == (tmp[-1]-tmp[-length(tmp)])) }` #--> TRUE.

Comment: @hadley, thanks its always good to get cleaner syntax. @Shane I know that diff already exists in R, but I wanted to compare the same operation.

Comment: @Matti I can understand you want to compare similar code, but if I compare languages, I use the best tools in each of them. Personally, I like to squeeze the last drop out of the lemon.

Comment: Sure, but in this case I wanted to show the difference in vectorised operations. The same speed difference applies if you e.g multiply a vector with number etc. Mind you the rdiff function runs at the same speed as the native diff in R.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a Java arrays implementation that is on my system faster than your R code (YMMV). Note enabling the reflection warnings, which is essential when optimizing for performance, and the repeated type hint on y (the one on the def didn't seem to help for the aset) and casting everything to primitive double values (the dotimes makes sure that i is a primitive int).

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(use 'incanter.stats)
(def ^"[D" x (double-array (sample-normal 1e7)))

(time
 (do
   (def ^"[D" y (double-array (dec (count x))))
   (dotimes [i (dec (count x))]
     (aset ^"[D" y
       i
       (double (- (double (aget x (inc i)))
                  (double (aget x i))))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, your code also runs faster than R on my system (it took 400 msecs), but if start the timing from x being a Clojure vector and convert y also back to a vector using the "vec" command it actually takes in total (from input vector to output vector) 4.5s more. Still your solution is ~3x faster than the original one and much closer to R! I especially appreciate such a good example on type hinting because that's something I've been struggling with.

Comment: note that the core team is working on better number performance in Clojure 1.3. http://combinate.us/clojure/2010/09/27/clojure/

Comment: @nickik, thanks for the link. I'm looking forward to the release.

Comment: @Matti Pastell: Look at transiants, they should speed up the convertions from array to vector alot more. http://clojure.org/transients

Comment: I suspect that the slowness of the array-to-vector conversion is due to creating all those boxed Double objects.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on *why* you want to use exactly vectors? Arrays are "seqable", meaning that the usual sequence operations work on them just fine.

Comment: I think that's actually a good point, I didn't actually know that most of the functions work also on arrays. It seems that its smart to run the whole computation with arrays and only convert to vectors or incanter.Matrix e.g. for plotting in the end.

Comment: Do you whats the difference between nth and aget? Is there any?

Comment: Aget is for indexing arrays, nth is for generic sequences.

Comment: I get that, but what about when you call nth on an array? Is it the same as using aget or is there some performance difference etc?

Comment: Of course aget has the potential to be faster, since it avoids some type checks before the array access and possibly the boxing of primitives, but the only way to know is to measure it in the actual context where you want to use it. JIT will likely be able to shortcut many of those type checks.

Comment: You can also hint with `^doubles` instead of `^"[D"`.

Answer (score 20):

### My final solutions

After all the testing I found two slightly different ways to do the calculation with sufficient speed.

First I've used the function `diff` with different types of return values, below is the code returning a vector, but I have also timed a version returning a double-array (replace (vec y) with y)  and Incanter.matrix (replace (vec y) with matrix y). This function is only based on java arrays. This is based on Jouni's code with some extra type hints removed.

Another approach is to do the calculations with Java arrays and store the values in a transient vector. As you see from the timings this is slightly faster than approach 1 if you wan't the function to return and array. This is implemented in function `difft`.

So the choice really depends on what you wan't to do with the data. I guess a good option would be to overload the function so that it returns the same type that was used in the call. Actually passing a java array to diff instead of a vector makes ~1s faster.

### **Timings for the different functions:**

**diff returning vector:**

```
(time (def y (diff x)))
"Elapsed time: 4733.259 msecs"
```

**diff returning Incanter.matrix:**

```
(time (def y (diff x)))
"Elapsed time: 2599.728 msecs"
```

**diff returning double-array:**

```
(time (def y (diff x)))
"Elapsed time: 1638.548 msecs"
```

**difft:**

```
(time (def y (difft x)))
"Elapsed time: 3683.237 msecs"
```

### **The functions**

```
(use 'incanter.stats)
(def x (vec (sample-normal 1e7)))

(defn diff [x]
  (let [y (double-array (dec (count x)))
        x (double-array x)] 
   (dotimes [i (dec (count x))]
     (aset y i
       (- (aget x (inc i))
                   (aget x i))))
   (vec y)))


(defn difft [x]
  (let [y (vector (range n))
        y (transient y)
        x (double-array x)]
   (dotimes [i (dec (count x))]
     (assoc! y i
       (- (aget x (inc i))
                   (aget x i))))
   (persistent! y)))
```

Comment: This is great work.  When you're finished, you should send your function back to the Incanter mailing list so that it can be included there...

Comment: Sorry I get frustrated from people making claims about Clojure's performance w/o the experience to make any sort of claims. This answer should be marked as the correct one please. The other will encourage people to use unnecessary type-hinting.

Comment: According to official docs "transients are not designed to be bashed in-place". You should use `assoc!` exactly like it will be natural `assoc`. So your last lines should look something like this `(persistent! (areduce (assoc! ...) x))` - instead of `dotimes`

Answer (score 2):

[Bradford Cross's blog](http://measuringmeasures.com/blog/2010/3/27/fast-clojure-vectors-and-multidimensional-arrays.html) has a bunch of posts about this (he uses this stuff for the startup he works on [link text](http://www.flightcaster.com). In general, using transients in inner loops, type hinting (via `*warn-on-reflection*`) etc are all good for speed increases. The Joy of Clojure has a great section on performance tuning, which you should read.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that he has also written Infer library (http://github.com/bradford/infer ) that includes some fairly fast vector operations using UJMP (http://www.ujmp.org/). Unfortenately the conversion from Clojure vector to infer.matrix is really slow (~30s for 1e7).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with transients - appealing but slow.

```
(use 'incanter.stats)
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(def x (doall (sample-normal 1e7)))

(time
 (def y
      (loop [xs x
             xs+ (rest x)
             result (transient [])]
        (if (empty? xs+)
          (persistent! result)
          (recur (rest xs) (rest xs+)
                 (conj! result (- (double (first xs+))
                                  (double (first xs)))))))))
```

Comment: I've updated my solution to mixture of transient and aget, its slightly faster than storing the result with aset and converting to a vector. Note that using "assoc!" on a preallocated vector is faster than "conj!".

Answer (score 0):

All the comments thus far are by people who don't seem to have much experience speeding up Clojure code. If you want Clojure code to perform identical to Java - the facilities are available to do so. It may make more sense however to defer to mature Java libraries like Colt or Parallel Colt for vector math. It may make sense to use Java arrays for the absolute highest performance iteration.

@Shane's link is so full of outdated information to be hardly worth looking at. Also @Shane's comment that code is slower than by factor of 10 is simply inaccurate (and unsupported http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/compare.php?lang=clojure, and these benchmarks don't account for the kinds of optimization possible in 1.2.0 or 1.3.0-alpha1). With a little bit of work it's usually easy to get Clojure code w/in 4X-5X. Beyond that usually requires a deeper knowledge of Clojure's fast paths - something isn't widely disseminated as Clojure is a fairly young language.

Clojure is plenty fast. But learning how to make it fast is going to take a bit of work/research as Clojure discourages mutable operations and mutable datastructures.

Comment: Thanks, could you maybe give me an example using Parallel Colt from Clojure? I know Incanter uses Parallel Colt for some things, but I guess not for the vector math since its so slow.

Comment: The language shootout (a) doesn't include R and (b) doesn't necessarily address the kinds of problems that Matti is considering (i.e. vectorized operations).  And to the extent that the benchmarking question is outdated, why don't you do us all a favor and update it!

Comment: >> these benchmarks don't account for the kinds of optimization possible in 1.2.0 << The benchmarks game measurements were made with Clojure 1.2.0 so contribute programs that use the optimizations you're hinting at.

Comment: I don't see any suggestions in your post. Shanes link is actually continuously updated, and contains still a lot of valid information, contributed by him and others. Stay fair, will ya? Chopenhauer also resorted to "that's plain bogus" if he didn't have any decent arguments. He actually made an art out of that, but one I don't like to see in discussions. It says more about the speaker than about the topic so to say...