# Scala type programming resources

Tags: scala, types

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047512/the-type-system-in-scala-is-turing-complete-proof-example-benefits), Scala's type system is [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). What resources are available that enable a newcomer to take advantage of the power of type-level programming?

Here are the resources I've found so far:

- [Daniel Spiewak's *High Wizardry in the Land of Scala*](http://vimeo.com/13518456)
- [Apocalisp's *Type-Level Programming in Scala*](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/)
- [Jesper's *HList*](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html)

These resources are great, but I feel like I'm missing the basics, and so do not have a solid foundation on which to build. For instance, where is there an introduction to type definitions? What operations can I perform on types?

Are there any good introductory resources?

Comment: Personally, I find the assumption that someone who wants to do type-level programming in Scala already knows how to do programming in Scala quite reasonable. Even if it means I don't understand a word of those articles you linked to :-)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**Overview**

Type-level programming has many similarities with traditional, value-level programming. However, unlike value-level programming, where the computation occurs at runtime, in type-level programming, the computation occurs at compile time. I will try to draw parallels between programming at the value-level and programming at the type-level.

**Paradigms**

There are two main paradigms in type-level programming: "object-oriented" and "functional". Most examples linked to from here follow the object-oriented paradigm.

A good, fairly simple example of type-level programming in the object-oriented paradigm can be found in apocalisp's [implementation of the lambda calculus](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/more-scala-typehackery/), replicated here:

```
// Abstract trait
trait Lambda {
  type subst[U <: Lambda] <: Lambda
  type apply[U <: Lambda] <: Lambda
  type eval <: Lambda
}

// Implementations
trait App[S <: Lambda, T <: Lambda] extends Lambda {
  type subst[U <: Lambda] = App[S#subst[U], T#subst[U]]
  type apply[U] = Nothing
  type eval = S#eval#apply[T]
}

trait Lam[T <: Lambda] extends Lambda {
  type subst[U <: Lambda] = Lam[T]
  type apply[U <: Lambda] = T#subst[U]#eval
  type eval = Lam[T]
}

trait X extends Lambda {
  type subst[U <: Lambda] = U
  type apply[U] = Lambda
  type eval = X
}
```

As can be seen in the example, the object-oriented paradigm for type-level programming proceeds as follows:

- First: define an abstract trait with various abstract type fields (see below for what an abstract field is). This is a template for guaranteeing that certain types fields exist in all implementations without forcing an implementation. In the lambda calculus example, this corresponds to `trait Lambda` that guarantees that the following types exist: `subst`, `apply`, and `eval`.
- Next: define subtraits that extend the abstract trait and implement the various abstract type fields

  - Often, these subtraits will be parameterized with arguments. In the lambda calculus example, the subtypes are `trait App extends Lambda` which is parameterized with two types (`S` and `T`, both must be subtypes of `Lambda`), `trait Lam extends Lambda` parameterized with one type (`T`), and `trait X extends Lambda` (which is not parameterized).
  - the type fields are often implemented by referring to the type parameters of the subtrait and sometimes referencing their type fields via the hash operator: `#` (which is very similar to the dot operator: `.` for values). In trait `App` of the lambda calculus example, the type `eval` is implemented as follows: `type eval = S#eval#apply[T]`. This is essentially calling the `eval` type of the trait's parameter `S`, and calling `apply` with parameter `T` on the result. Note, `S` is guaranteed to have an `eval` type because the parameter specifies it to be a subtype of `Lambda`. Similarly, the result of `eval` must have an `apply` type, since it is specified to be a subtype of `Lambda`, as specified in the abstract trait `Lambda`.

The Functional paradigm consists of defining lots of parameterized type constructors that are not grouped together in traits.

**Comparison between value-level programming and type-level programming**

- [abstract class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105)

  - value-level: `abstract class C { val x }`
  - type-level: `trait C { type X }`
- path dependent types

  - `C.x` (referencing field value/function x in object C)
  - `C#x` (referencing field type x in trait C)
- function signature (no implementation)

  - value-level: `def f(x:X) : Y`
  - type-level: `type f[x <: X] <: Y` (this is called a "type constructor" and usually occurs in the abstract trait)
- function implementation

  - value-level: `def f(x:X) : Y = x`
  - type-level: `type f[x <: X] = x`
- conditionals

  - [see here](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-3-boolean/)
- checking equality

  - value-level: `a:A == b:B`
  - type-level: `implicitly[A =:= B]`
  - value-level: Happens in the JVM via a unit test at runtime (i.e. no runtime errors):

    - in essense is an assert: `assert(a == b)`
  - type-level: Happens in the compiler via a typecheck (i.e. no compiler errors):

    - in essence is a type comparison: e.g. `implicitly[A =:= B]`
    - `A <:< B`, compiles only if `A` is a subtype of `B`
    - `A =:= B`, compiles only if `A` is a subtype of `B` and `B` is a subtype of `A`
    - `A <%< B`, ("viewable as") compiles only if `A` is viewable as `B` (i.e. there is an implicit conversion from `A` to a subtype of `B`)
    - [an example](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-generalized-type-constraints-how.html)
    - [more comparison operators](https://gist.github.com/257758/47f06f2f3ca47702b3a86c76a5479d096cb8c7ec)

**Converting between types and values**

- In many of the examples, types defined via traits are often both abstract and sealed, and therefore can neither be instantiated directly nor via anonymous subclass. So it is common to use `null` as a placeholder value when doing a value-level computation using some type of interest:

  - e.g. `val x:A = null`, where `A` is the type you care about
- Due to type-erasure, parameterized types all look the same. Furthermore, (as mentioned above) the values you're working with tend to all be `null`, and so conditioning on the object type (e.g. via a match statement) is ineffective.

The trick is to use implicit functions and values. The base case is usually an implicit value and the recursive case is usually an implicit function. Indeed, type-level programming makes heavy use of implicits.

Consider this example ([taken from metascala](http://trac.assembla.com/metascala/browser/src/metascala/Nats.scala) and [apocalisp](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-4a-peano-number-basics/)):

```
sealed trait Nat
sealed trait _0 extends Nat
sealed trait Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat
```

Here you have a peano encoding of the natural numbers. That is, you have a type for each non-negative integer: a special type for 0, namely `_0`; and each integer greater than zero has a type of the form `Succ[A]`, where `A` is the type representing a smaller integer. For instance, the type representing 2 would be: `Succ[Succ[_0]]` (successor applied twice to the type representing zero).

We can alias various natural numbers for more convenient reference. Example:

```
type _3 = Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]
```

(This is a lot like defining a `val` to be the result of a function.)

Now, suppose we want to define a value-level function `def toInt[T <: Nat](v : T)` which takes in an argument value, `v`, that conforms to `Nat` and returns an integer representing the natural number encoded in `v`'s type. For example, if we have the value `val x:_3 = null` (`null` of type `Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]`), we would want `toInt(x)` to return `3`.

To implement `toInt`, we're going to make use of the following class:

```
class TypeToValue[T, VT](value : VT) { def getValue() = value }
```

As we will see below, there will be an object constructed from class `TypeToValue` for each `Nat` from `_0` up to (e.g.) `_3`, and each will store the value representation of the corresponding type (i.e. `TypeToValue[_0, Int]` will store the value `0`, `TypeToValue[Succ[_0], Int]` will store the value `1`, etc.). Note, `TypeToValue` is parameterized by two types: `T` and `VT`. `T` corresponds to the type we're trying to assign values to (in our example, `Nat`) and `VT` corresponds to the type of value we're assigning to it (in our example, `Int`).

Now we make the following two implicit definitions:

```
implicit val _0ToInt = new TypeToValue[_0, Int](0)
implicit def succToInt[P <: Nat](implicit v : TypeToValue[P, Int]) = 
     new TypeToValue[Succ[P], Int](1 + v.getValue())
```

And we implement `toInt` as follows:

```
def toInt[T <: Nat](v : T)(implicit ttv : TypeToValue[T, Int]) : Int = ttv.getValue()
```

To understand how `toInt` works, let's consider what it does on a couple of inputs:

```
val z:_0 = null
val y:Succ[_0] = null
```

When we call `toInt(z)`, the compiler looks for an implicit argument `ttv` of type `TypeToValue[_0, Int]` (since `z` is of type `_0`). It finds the object `_0ToInt`, it calls the `getValue` method of this object and gets back `0`. The important point to note is that we did not specify to the program which object to use, the compiler found it implicitly.

Now let's consider `toInt(y)`. This time, the compiler looks for an implicit argument `ttv` of type `TypeToValue[Succ[_0], Int]` (since `y` is of type `Succ[_0]`). It finds the function `succToInt`, which can return an object of the appropriate type (`TypeToValue[Succ[_0], Int]`) and evaluates it. This function itself takes an implicit argument (`v`) of type `TypeToValue[_0, Int]` (that is, a `TypeToValue` where the first type parameter is has one fewer `Succ[_]`). The compiler supplies `_0ToInt` (as was done in the evaluation of `toInt(z)` above), and `succToInt` constructs a new `TypeToValue` object with value `1`. Again, it is important to note that the compiler is providing all of these values implicitly, since we do not have access to them explicitly.

**Checking your work**

There are several ways to verify that your type-level computations are doing what you expect. Here are a few approaches. Make two types `A` and `B`, that you want to verify are equal. Then check that the following compile:

- `Equal[A, B]`

  - with: trait `Equal[T1 >: T2 <: T2, T2]` ([taken from apocolisp](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/more-scala-typehackery/))
- `implicitly[A =:= B]`

Alternatively, you can convert the type to a value (as shown above) and do a runtime check of the values. E.g. `assert(toInt(a) == toInt(b))`, where `a` is of type `A` and `b` is of type `B`.

**Additional Resources**

The complete set of available constructs can be found in the types section of [the scala reference manual (pdf)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

[Adriaan Moors](http://adriaanm.github.com/) has several academic papers about type constructors and related topics with examples from scala:

- [Generics of a higher kind (pdf)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.135.575&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [Type Constructor Polymorphism for Scala: Theory and Practice (pdf)](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/1979/2642/5/thesis_adriaan_moors_archive.pdf) (PhD thesis, which includes the previous paper by Moors)
- [Type Constructor Polymorphism Inference](http://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/)

[Apocalisp](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/) is a blog with many examples of type-level programming in scala.

- [Type-Level Programming in Scala](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) is a fantastic guided tour of some type-level programming which includes booleans, natural numbers (as above), binary numbers, heterogeneous lists, and more.
- [More Scala Typehackery](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/more-scala-typehackery/) is the lambda calculus implementation above.

[ScalaZ](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) is a very active project that is providing functionality that extends the Scala API using various type-level programming features. It is a very interesting project that has a big following.

[MetaScala](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/metascala) is a type-level library for Scala, including meta types for natural numbers, booleans, units, HList, etc. It is a project by [Jesper Nordenberg (his blog)](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/).

The [Michid (blog)](http://michid.wordpress.com/) has some awesome examples of type-level programming in Scala (from other answer):

- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part I: Addition](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/meta-programming-with-scala-part-i-addition/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part II: Multiplication](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/meta-programming-with-scala-part-ii-multiplication/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part III: Partial function application](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/meta-programming-with-scala-part-iii-partial-function-application/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala: Conditional Compilation and Loop Unrolling](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/meta-programming-with-scala-conditional-compilation-and-loop-unrolling/)
- [Scala type level encoding of the SKI calculus](http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/scala-type-level-encoding-of-the-ski-calculus/)

[Debasish Ghosh (blog)](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/) has some relevant posts as well:

- [Higher order abstractions in scala](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2009/01/higher-order-abstractions-in-scala-with.html)
- [Static typing gives you a head start](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2009/08/static-typing-gives-you-head-start.html)
- [Scala implicits type classes, here I come](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/06/scala-implicits-type-classes-here-i.html)
- [Refactoring into scala type-classes](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/07/refactoring-into-scala-type-classes.html)
- [Using generalized type constraints](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-generalized-type-constraints-how.html)
- [How scalas type system words for you](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-scalas-type-system-works-for-your.html)
- [Choosing between abstract type members](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/05/choosing-between-abstract-type-members.html)

(I've been doing some research on this subject and here's what I've learned. I'm still new to it, so please point out any inaccuracies in this answer.)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the other links here, there are also my blog posts on type level meta programming in Scala:

- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part I: Addition](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/meta-programming-with-scala-part-i-addition/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part II: Multiplication](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/meta-programming-with-scala-part-ii-multiplication/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala Part III: Partial function application](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/meta-programming-with-scala-part-iii-partial-function-application/)
- [Meta-Programming with Scala: Conditional Compilation and Loop Unrolling](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/meta-programming-with-scala-conditional-compilation-and-loop-unrolling/)
- [Scala type level encoding of the SKI calculus](http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/scala-type-level-encoding-of-the-ski-calculus/)

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the interesting blog; I've been following it for a while and especially the last post mentioned above has sharpened my understanding of important properties a type system for an object oriented language should have.  So, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As suggested on Twitter: [Shapeless: An exploration of generic/polytypic programming in Scala](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)  by Miles Sabin.

Answer (score 5):

- [Sing](https://github.com/okomok/sing), a type-level metaprogramming library in Scala.
- *[The Beginning of Type-level Programming in Scala](https://github.com/okomok/sing/wiki/design-guidelines)*

Answer (score 4):

[**Scalaz**](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) has source code, a wiki and examples.