# What does 'do not conform to trait Builder's type parameter bounds' mean in scala?

Tags: scala, types, type-systems, generic-type-argument, abstract-type

I have the following simple program that defines 2 identical upper bounds for type parameter and abstract type alias respectively:

```
package scala.spike.typeBoundInference

object Example1 {
  trait Domain {
  }

  trait Impl {

    type DD <: Domain
    type GG <: StaticGraph[DD]

    type A1
    type A2
    type A3
    // ... this type list can go very long
    // so inlining them as generic type parameters is impossible


    final type Builder = StaticGraph.Builder[DD, GG]
  }

  trait DSL[I <: Impl] {

    val impl: StaticGraph.Builder[I#DD, I#GG]
  }

  trait StaticGraph[T <: Domain] {}

  object StaticGraph {

    trait Builder[D <: Domain, G <: StaticGraph[D]] {}

  }
}
```

However, scala refuse to compile it:

> Error:(16, 27) type arguments [I#DD,I#GG] do not conform to trait
>   Builder's type parameter bounds [D <:
>   scala.spike.typeBoundInference.Example1.Domain,G <:
>   scala.spike.typeBoundInference.Example1.StaticGraph[D]]
>       val impl: StaticGraph.Builder[I#DD, I#GG]

What could possibly go wrong here?

- DD <: Domain check
- GG <: StaticGraph[DD] check

there is no reason scala think it is unsafe.

In the meantime, I found that if class StaticGraph[T] is declared as covariant scala compiler will run successfully. This is even worse (for some reason StaticGraph[T] has to be invariant), as type bound GG <: StaticGraph[DD] means that if type DD is determined, then GG is a subclass of StaticGraph[DD], but not necessary a subclass of StaticGraph[Domain], which is exactly what I want here.

**UPDATE 1**: I've read all the answers and comments and somehow got the impression that the core reason is that there is no guarantee that for any instance `i` of `Impl`, the type bound only guarantee that type

`i.DD <:< Impl#DD` and `Imp#GG <:< StaticGraph[Impl#DD]`

but not `StaticGraph[i.DD] <:< StaticGraph[Impl#GG]`

thus `i.GG <:< StaticGraph[i.DD]` is also not guaranteed.

However, I've done a quick experiment to verify this idea, which turns out to be not ture:

```
object Example1 {

  trait Domain {}
  class D1 extends Domain {}

  trait Impl {

    type DD <: Domain
    type GG <: StaticGraph[DD]
  }

  class StaticGraph[T <: Domain] {}

  object Impl1 extends Impl {

    type DD = D1
    type GG = StaticGraph[Domain]
  }

  //or this:

  val impl = new Impl {

    type DD = D1
    type GG = StaticGraph[Domain]
  }
}
```

In this case compiler throw an error:

> Error:(19, 10) overriding type GG in trait Impl with bounds <:
>   scala.spike.TypeBoundInference.Example1.StaticGraph[scala.spike.TypeBoundInference.Example1.Impl1.DD];
>   type GG has incompatible type
>       type GG = StaticGraph[Domain]

If you think the type constraint doesn't hold for some instances, could you give me counter example?

**UPDATE2**: turns out that according to the answer, this is true:

`i.GG <:< StaticGraph[i.DD]`

but this maybe false:

`Impl#GG <:< StaticGraph[Impl#GG]`.

so in the context of DSL this may also be false:

`I#GG <:< StaticGraph[I#GG]` (3)

But this is only part of the puzzle, to prove that it is type unsafe, we have to construct a counter example of DSL[I] that invalidates condition (3). So the old question remains: is it possible to construct a counter example?

Comment: Shorter example: `trait StaticGraph[T];

  trait Impl {
    type DD;
    type GG <: StaticGraph[DD]
  };

  def f[I <: Impl]: Unit = {
    implicitly[I#GG <:< StaticGraph[I#DD]]
  }`

Comment: Nice! your example is much better, as the error information directly shows the irony:
Error:(12, 40) Cannot prove that I#GG <:< scala.spike.TypeBoundInference.Example3.StaticGraph[I#DD]

Comment: Why don't you use `I#Builder` instead?, it works for me.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah it is a valid bypass, but they are the same thing, so theoretically I don't have to do it.

Comment: They aren't the same thing: `I#Builder` is (approximately) `StaticGraph.Builder[i.DD, i.GG] forSome { val i: I }`, and `StaticGraph.Builder[I#DD, I#GG]` is `StaticGraph.Builder[i1.DD forSome { val i1: I }, i2.GG forSome { val i2: I} ]`.

Comment: If you don't want to define `Builder` in `Impl` and use `I#Builder`, you can write `val impl: StaticGraph.Builder[i.DD, i.GG] forSome { val i: I }` explicitly and that works too.

Comment: For update: it's the other way around. `i.GG <:< StaticGraph[i.DD]` is guaranteed, `Impl#GG <:< StaticGraph[Impl#DD]` is not. The error is because you need either `type DD = Domain` or `type GG = StaticGraph[D1]`.

Comment: I got your point, thanks a lot! Will add it as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Problem solved:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

object Example5 {

  trait Domain {}
  trait D1 extends Domain

  trait Impl {

    type DD <: Domain
    type GG[T <: Domain] <: StaticGraph[T]
  }

  trait DSL[I <: Impl] {

    val impl: Builder[I#DD, I#GG]
  }

  trait StaticGraph[T <: Domain] {}

  trait Builder[D <: Domain, G[T <: Domain] <: StaticGraph[T]] {}
}
```

I can't believe I have to use higher kind for such banal matter :-<

Why it compiles? It decouples type constraint and delay it until it becomes necessary. (this is the only explanation I can think of)

Answer (score 2):

> What could possibly go wrong here?
>
> GG <: StaticGraph[DD] check

By declaring `type GG <: StaticGraph[DD]` you establish a relationship between *member* types (it's the same as `<: StaticGraph[this.DD]`). This means that you need to consider instances of `Impl`.

For any `val i: Impl`, you have `i.DD <: Domain` and `i.GG <: StaticGraph[i.DD]`. You also have `i.DD <: I#DD`. But you *don't* have `i.DD =:= I#DD`! So `StaticGraph[i.DD]` and `StaticGraph[I#DD]` are not related (for invariant `StaticGraph`). And so neither are `i.GG` (or `I#GG`) and `StaticGraph[I#DD]`.

To make it compile, you need to require that all `i.DD` are the same (which also guarantee `i.DD =:= I#DD`). And there is a way to do that:

```
trait DSL[T <: Domain, I <: Impl { type DD = T } ]
```

will make the code compile (without any other changes).

If `StaticGraph` is covariant, the relationships work out:

```
I#GG =:= (kind of)
i.GG forSome { val i: I } <:
StaticGraph[i.DD] forSome { val i: I } <:
StaticGraph[I#DD] forSome { val i: I } =:=
StaticGraph[I#DD]
```

Comment: Sorry, what is "`kind of`"? I found your initial prose-explanation clearer. Now I'm confused. And what's with those `<:`? Should they be `<:<`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin They are not exactly the same (according to `=:=`) but they have the same values. `implicitly[I#GG =:= i.GG forSome { val i: I }]` actually results in `Cannot prove that I#GG =:= I#GG`.

Comment: Oh, those fantastic "cannot prove X =:= X` error messages again. This somehow vaguely reminds me of [this strange compiler behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687591/does-scala-have-syntax-for-projection-of-a-nested-singleton-type) that you discovered ~11 months ago, you seem to have some kind of special sense for finding those strange examples :)

Comment: The `<:` is correct (because it's the relation between types), the problem is that there's no corresponding notation for `=:=` :)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I edited a bit to restore the prose explanation for the invariant case (though SO lost the original revision). Do you think this is better?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov the problem is that in my code i is never instantiated, and there is no such thing referred as StaticGraph[i.DD] (Impl is intend to be only used to reduce the number of generic type parameters, the only possible concrete instance is for DSL), if it exists I have no problem reading the error

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov in addition, the i have 2 ways to inherit type DD: i.DD can be a nested class (which caused the lack of relationship you mentioned), or it can continue to be a type alias (which has no such effect). Regardless, is there a short solution to silence the compiler?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, also, may I ask a favour to post the complete scala code for type constraint check? For beginners it is hard to speculate what is happening without actually compiling it.

Comment: @tribbloid 1. Not instantiating `Impl` doesn't change what it means. `type GG <: StaticGraph[DD]` makes a constraint on _member_ types, and doesn't (directly) say anything about projection types `I#GG`/`I#DD` at all. In the covariant case, the compiler can prove projection types are related using the relationship on member types; in the invariant case, it can't.

Comment: @tribbloid 2. You are missing an important case: it can not be implemented at all. E.g. it isn't for `Impl` itself, which is a valid type argument for `DSL`. Because the definition of `DSL` doesn't work for _this_ case (`Impl#DD` is not a subtype of `StaticGraph[Impl#GG]`), it doesn't work in general, so the compiler doesn't let it through.

Comment: @tribbloid I've extended the answer and added another change which would make your code correct.

Comment: Saw your update, thanks a lot!
I agree that 'But you don't have i.DD =:= I#DD'. But that solution is impractical, in real case DSL need to refer to scores of member types, which can easily blow up the cap for generic type parameters

Comment: To sum up: path-dependent types are already not too obvious, and type projections are worse. You'll likely be better off adding an instance of `I` and using path-dependent types directly, but I can't guarantee that without knowing your DSL in more detail.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov obviously I only have 2 options here: either use type projections or use a long list (> 30) of generic type parameters, both are impossible, this means the type system is broken and should be completely avoided.