# What is the Scala type-programming analogy for the `this` keyword?

Tags: scala, types, metaprogramming

I'm trying to work my way into understanding type-programming in Scala, and I've found that most of what one needs to know about type programming has an analogous counterpart in value programming as is reflected in [the type-level programming wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415511/scala-type-programming-resources#answer-4443972).  However, I've not found the analogy for the `this` key word or self-types.  I suspect maybe it doesn't make sense to expect such a thing, but I thought I would ask.

For instance, I can write the following to represent Booleans as values at run time:

```scala
sealed trait BoolVal {
  def not:BoolVal
  def or(that:BoolVal):BoolVal
  def and(that:BoolVal) =
    (this.not or that.not).not
  def imp(that:BoolVal) =
    this.not or that
}
case object TrueVal extends BoolVal {
  override val not = FalseVal
  override def or(that:BoolVal) = TrueVal
}
case object FalseVal extends BoolVal {
  override val not = TrueVal
  override def or(that:BoolVal) = that
}
```

Here my `and` and `imp` are able to take advantage of the fact it doesn't matter if I am a false object or a true object to be defined correctly.  My `TrueVal` and `FalseVal` objects can inherit the same code.

I can make the analogous type-level programming constructs, but I don't understand how to define `And` and `Imp` in my base trait.

```scala
sealed trait BoolType {
  type Not <: BoolType
  type Or[That <: BoolType] <: BoolType
  type And[That <: BoolType] = ???
  type Imp[That <: BoolType] = ???
}
sealed trait TrueType extends BoolType {
  override type Not = FalseType
  override type Or[That <: BoolType] = TrueType
}
sealed trait FalseType extends BoolType {
  override type Not = TrueType
  override type Or[That <: BoolType] = That
}
```

I can see where perhaps it doesn't make sense that my types inherit types, but the certainly inherit abstract types.  Is there a way to define `And` and `Impl` in my `BoolType`, or do I have to define each in the respective `TrueType` and `FalseType` traits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always define an abstract type on your boolean base type as follows:

```
trait MyBool extends BoolType{
  type This <: BoolType
}

trait TrueType extends BoolType{
  type This = TrueType
}
```

and you should be good to go with a reference to yourself. Then you can use DeMorgan's Laws to do the following

```
 !(x && y) == (!x || !y)
```

Then by a double negative you can get you `And` condition going:

```
 !(!x || !y) == !!(x && y) == (x && y)
```

Comment: DeMorgan's is exactly what I am shooting for like in my `BoolVal` trait.  But... I tried your suggesting, but it but it didn't compile.  In particular, the definitions for `And` and `Imp` didn't compile: `type And[That <: BoolType] = This.Not.Or[That.Not].Not` and `type Imp[That <: BoolType] = This.Not.Or[That]`

Comment: Don't use `This.Not` I would try using `This#Not`. You're working at the type level, now.

Comment: #FacePalm #MidnightPilotError #BeerThirty

Comment: And for good measure, I used `protected` on my `This` types.  Thanks a million! I'm writing a blog post with what I've learned. I'll post it back here.  Would love your feedback if you have time.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using `self`, example of your blog post adjusted:

```
sealed trait BoolType { self =>
  type Not <: BoolType
  type Or[That <: BoolType] <: BoolType
  type And[That <: BoolType] = self.type#Not#Or[That#Not]#Not
  type Imp[That <: BoolType] = self.type#Not#Or[That]
}
sealed trait TrueType extends BoolType {
  override type Not = FalseType
  override type Or[That <: BoolType] = TrueType
}
sealed trait FalseType extends BoolType {
  override type Not = TrueType
  override type Or[That <: BoolType] = That
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, arguably more than creating a `This` type, since it keeps stuff from leaking out. I'll definitely make this change moving forward and note it in the follow up post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the `this` keyword? When i explored type level programming myself, i could not see a difference when using this instead of self.

```
sealed trait BoolType {
  type Not <: BoolType 
  type Or[That <: BoolType] <: BoolType
  type And[That <: BoolType] = this.type#Not#Or[That#Not]#Not
  type Imp[That <: BoolType] = this.type#Not#Or[That]
}
```

Comment: I agree with you. In fact, once I compiled my excursion into an article, I chose this exact approach (no pun intended)

Comment: I recently stumbled upon your great blog series about that topic. I will give an introduction talk to type level programming at a local meetup. Your series serve as an example. So thanks for the great work!

Comment: Fantastic! I hope it goes well! Don't hesitate to contact me if you need any additional help.

Comment: This begs the question: What exactly is the difference between using `this` and a self type annotation? I know that you can express dependencies with the self type (`self: TraitToMixIn`), but that isn't needed here, so why else might one prefer to use self type to `this`? @joescii, have you formed an opinion by now?

Comment: @stewSquared There should be no difference (compiler weirdness might cause it though), the reason I use self instead of this is because all content that can be googled refers to it as a self type. And when you do add dependencies using the self type, the `self` is richer than `this`.