# Scala Co-Variant Bounded Types

Tags: scala

I'm playing with Scala's type system with the following example:

```
scala> sealed trait A
defined trait A

scala> case class A1(n: Int) extends A
defined class A1

scala> case class A2(n: Int) extends A
defined class A2

scala> case class MyCase[+P <: A](a: A, y: String)
defined class MyCase

scala> val l = List(MyCase[A1](A1(1), "A1"), MyCase[A2](A2(2), "A2"))
```

Now, when I do the following:

```
scala> l.head.asInstanceOf[MyCase[A2]]
res2: MyCase[A2] = MyCase(A1(1),A1)
```

How can a `MyCase[A1]` instance be assigned to a `MyCase[A2]` reference? I mean `MyCase[A1]` and `MyCase[A2]` are at the same level in the object hierarchy!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion! My question was actually something. I modified my post above

Comment: What's the point of having the type parameter P at all, if it's not used?

Comment: *"how can `MyCase[A1]` object be assigned to a `MyCase[A2]` reference?"*  -- Because you're *forcing* it with a type cast.

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is an unsafe operation. You're telling the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing". If the cast is invalid, you might get a runtime error immediately, or you might not — you might just end up having problems later. `asInstanceOf` is never used in normal Scala code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you're wondering why you didn't get an error here in runtime, when you did `l.head.asInstanceOf[MyCase[A2]]`. So the answer is simple - [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). For JVM both types are equal as it ignores generic parameter - it simply doesn't know about them as they exist on compiler level only, so only compiler can give you an exception:

```
scala> val mcA2: MyCase[A2] = l.head
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : MyCase[Product with Serializable with A]
 required: MyCase[A2]
       val mcA2: MyCase[A2] = l.head
                                ^
```

However, `asInstanceOf` ignores this check. So when you do

```
case class MyCase[+P <: A](a: P) //P instead of A
scala> val k = MyCase[A1](A1(0)).asInstanceOf[MyCase[A2]]
k: MyCase[A2] = MyCase(A1(0))

scala> val a: A2 = k.a
java.lang.ClassCastException: A1 cannot be cast to A2
... 33 elided
```

But in your example - you never really used `P` in runtime (and it's impossible), so you never gonna get `ClassCastException`. Actually, under these conditions (no real instances), you can do type-level `copy` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470018/1809978), but it safer to use traits for that.

Comment: This exercise was just for me to understand Scala's Bounded types. I'm intrigued by the example thus far. Why would I then concern myself with bounded types? What are some typical use cases where I could use Bounded types?

Comment: It's simple, you can't even create `MyCase[String]` for instance, because it's bounded with `A` (without `asInstanceOf` of course). Covariance (`A >: B => M[A] >: M[B]`) is absolutely ortogonal to it, as long as `asInstanceOf`, it's just not related.