# scala compiler's stackoverflow protection

Tags: scala, scalac, halting-problem

In runtime I can:

```
def X(R: Any): Any = X(R)
```

But can't do simmilar thing for compile-time:

```
scala> type X[R] = X[R]
<console>:11: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type X
       type X[R] = X[R]
                   ^
```

Seems like infinite loop/recursion protection, but as far as I understand the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) - there is no general way to detect infinite recursion for [turing-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047512/the-type-system-in-scala-is-turing-complete-proof-example-benefits) language (as detector itself may not halt), so additional compiler's check will not generally work here.

So is there a way to get infinite recursion on scalac? And, is there any other (than preventing such recursion) reason to have `illegal cyclic reference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tricky way to get StackOverflow on scalac using recursion in combination with polymorphism:

```
scala> trait Re { type X[R <: Re] }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
defined trait Re

scala> trait ReRe extends Re {type X[R <: Re] = R#X[R]}
defined trait ReRe

scala> type X = ReRe#X[ReRe]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

It works because compiler think that `R#X[R]` is called on `Re`, but actually `ReRe` was passed when calculating `type X`.

No idea about purpose of `illegal cyclic reference` - maybe it protects only from infinite loops inside compiler, but not from infinite recursion (if turing-completeness is implemented using non-tail recursion).